# kubuntu 18.10 HDMI TV not working

Tags: kubuntu, hdmi, amd-graphics, xrandr

I have a Lenovo ideapad 310, with an AMD A12 APU and kubuntu 18.10. My graphics driver are the mesa drivers from ppa:Dibaf/graphics-drivers, of which the current version is 19.0~git1811211930.
When I plug an HDMI cable to a TV, there is no image on the TV. In kubuntu's screen settings, only the laptop display appears. But xrandr says it has detected the HDMI TV:

```
$xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.05*+
   1680x1050     60.05  
   1280x1024     60.05  
   1440x900      60.05  
   1280x800      60.05  
   1280x720      60.05  
   1024x768      60.05  
   800x600       60.05  
   640x480       60.05  
HDMI-A-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1152mm x 648mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And in kubuntu's screen configuration, clicking on the (i) button which I presume is for identifying the screens, both screen names appear superimposed on the laptop display:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJhoM.jpg)

Also commands such as:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --mode 1920x1080
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --auto --same-as eDP
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --auto --left-of eDP
```

do nothing.

Any help? thanks!

Comment: *UPDATE*: It worked on another TV, a common LED TV. It worked almost instantly, only the KDE screen settings do nothing. I only could change from clone to extend desktop, etc., using xrandr. On my TV, a Sanyo smart TV, it still doesn't work. The same laptop on my TV, using Windows, works OK.

Comment: UPDATE 2: I tried live USBs of xubuntu and Ubuntu, and it also doesn't work.

The smart tv model in which HDMI with linux doesn't work is the NOBLEX 32LD868HI, which is equivalent to the SANYO LCE32IH13, JVC LT32DA950 and PHILCO PLD3214HI.